# Add android jar to eclipse

Tags: java

When I open the android jar I'm not able to see .java files , it shows .class files in it .
Please suggest me how to add android jar to eclipse.

Waiting for an early response.

Comment: Err, that's what jar files do - provide a delivery mechanism for Java classes.  Why do you want the .java source files?

Comment: why do you want to add jar to eclipse, want to use the libraries? or want to check the source? If you want to see code, go to the source's website you will get the full documentation and source (if it opensource). If you want to reuse the code, learn about api and extend the classes adn reuse it. If you really want to see the .java files use http://java.decompiler.free.fr/

Comment: Because When I attach the android jar present inside android-sdk/platforms it doesn't work. Just see the below link , pic1 shows what I'm getting and last pic shows what I want.
http://www.farside.org.uk/200906/make_eclipse_show_android_source

Comment: I hope I cleared what I want, new to java dats why facing problem in it. I want to see the methods of any class of android jar in eclipse itself.

Comment: Have you actually tried following the steps described between the first and last picture in the link you provided?

Comment: Thank god finally it's done ...sorry for the inconvenience !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the java code of android you should better visit [Andrdoid x-86 branch wesite](http://www.android-x86.org/getsourcecode) and follow the instructions there.

But you can not see the java code by adding its JAR file in the eclipse project class path.

Comment: Its an open source. So you can play with it compile the code and make its ISO image and then create a Virtual matchine for it. Its a real fun!!! :)